# sql server check constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Am I missing something?
When I get SSMS to script a check constraint for create it produces two statements,

```
ALTER TABLE mytable  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_myconstraint] CHECK  (([Time]>='2011-05-15 20:33:00.000' AND [Time]<='2011-05-17 20:31:00.000'))
GO
ALTER TABLE mytable CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_myconstraint]
```

My understanding is that the "with check" should check the constraint on existing data when the constraint is being made. If this is true, why is it then checking the constraint again?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, you only need the first one.

Don't know why SSMS does this. I thought maybe this was some permutation of "Scripting" options under Tools..Options, but I don't see anything likely

Comment: My guess would be that they do it that way to support other options (such as using NOCHECK then performing some other action) and when you do the simple case they don't want to have to write different code if the code for the more complex case works any way. Just a guess though.